# Action of GL$(2,\mathbb{R})$ on symmetric matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

This is a problem from an old qualifier.

Let GL$(2,\mathbb{R})$ act on SYM, the real symmetric 2x2 matrices, via $S \mapsto A^T SA$ for $A \in$ GL$(2,\mathbb{R})$ and $S \in$SYM.  Show that each orbit has a representative which is a diagonal matrix with entries in $\{1,0,-1\}$.

I suppose one could use brute force by computing $A^TSA$ in terms of the entries of $A$ and $S$, setting one of the off-diagonal entries equal to $0$, and solving for $A$.  But I feel like there should be a nicer way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $S \in {\rm Sym}(n)$ is given, we find an $T \in O(n)$ such that $TST^t = TST^{-1} =: \Lambda$ is a real, diagonal matrix. Now write $\Lambda = {\rm diag}(\def\sgn{\mathop{\rm sgn}}\sgn \lambda_1, \ldots, \sgn \lambda_n) \cdot {\rm diag}(|\lambda_1|, \ldots, |\lambda_n|) =: \sgn\Lambda \cdot |\Lambda|$. $|\Lambda|$ can be written as $D^2$ for some diagonal $D$ (just take square roots of the elements). Then
$$ S = T^t\Lambda T = T^t \sgn\Lambda D^2 T = (DT)^t \cdot \sgn \Lambda \cdot (DT) $$
Now let $A = DT$.

Comment: Thanks!  I didn't know that real symmetric matrices are diagonalizable by orthogonal matrices until now.